# RedactionReasons modifier in iOS with AppStorage variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

I use AppStorage variable in my SwiftUI iOS app for saving some settings like language, dark mode state etc. I need to implement "Incognito mode" feature which will hide sensitive data in many different views. I use RedactionReasons modifier for this. But in my implementation changing of AppStore variable does not apply changes on views with this modifier. It works only after opening/closing app or when that views redraws by other reasons (like changed filters etc).

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct IncognitoModeView: View {

    var body: some View {
        SettingsView()
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .redacted(reason: AppSettings.shared.$incognitoMode.wrappedValue ? .placeholder : [])
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "sunglasses.fill")
                Text("Incognito mode")
            }
            Toggle("", isOn: AppSettings.shared.$incognitoMode)
        }
    }
}

class AppSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = AppSettings()
    
    @AppStorage("incognitoMode") var incognitoMode: Bool = false
}

#Preview {
    IncognitoModeView()
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}
```

Comment: AppStorage used to work inside an ObservableObject but this behavior changed a few updates ago. It is likely a bug but none the less you have to put it in the View. Also, it never worked as a singleton, you have to observe them somehow. Singletons are considered by many bad practice in most cases.